# Which monitoring tool is better to use on AWS for k8s cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, alert, monitoring, metrics

Running k8s cluster on AWS. Want to use a monitoring tool to do monitoring and alerting. The most famous one is `Prometheus`. But the k8s official suggests `Heapster`. Which is better? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no better or worse here, you need both :)

Heapster is a solution that makes it possible for Prometheus to collect metrics for the kube cluster. It is also intended to be replaced by [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) eventually. Heapster will also allow things like `kubectl top pods` to work, but will not give you a long term metrics storage / analysis / alerting. For that, you need something like Prometheus+Grafana.

Comment: We have recently compiled a technical overview page about Prometheus, please take a look here: https://www.weave.works/technologies/monitoring-kubernetes-with-prometheus/.